# How to sort tableview in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tableview

I am designing an app for ios that allows you to keep track of different people that owe you money. The basic interface allows you to go in and enter the persons name, the date they intend to pay you back and the amount they owe. All this information is then sent to its own array (namearray, datearray,totalarray) and displayed in a tableview. Is there anyway I can sort the table view to provide multiple sorting options such as having the person who owes you the most money be on top of the table view instead of just the order they were entered in?

Comment: have you tried to find out your solution?

Comment: You do not want three arrays. You want one array. That should be an array of a class/struct that represents a name, date, and amount.

Comment: and you do not want to sort a tableview, you want to sort the underlying data

Answer (score 0):

You don't need three array, you want to have one array of your information.

You need to sort your array based on your need before `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called, that way you could use it to display your sorted information at each row.

If you want to apply another sort, then sort your array containing all your info, call `reloadData()` it gonna call `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` once again, but since you sorted your array in another way, the result will be different.